How do I sign in in a before hook when writing system tests?
I have a Ruby on Rails application with RSpec, Capybara and Selenium with Chromium/Chrome. Because I need to sign in before I can test any application features I visit / first, get redirected to the sign-in form and fill in credentials. After that I can visit any other page or navigate the application. When I do this in an example, everything works fine:
it 'shows users' do
  visit('/')

  fill_in('user_username', with: 'test')
  fill_in('user_password', with: 'testing123')

  click_on('Sign In')

  visit('/users')

  expect(page).to have_text('Users')
end

However, I actually need to sign in for every example, so I moved the code up to a before hook.
before :each do
  visit('/')

  fill_in('user_username', with: 'test')
  fill_in('user_password', with: 'testing123')

  click_on('Sign In')
end

it 'shows users' do
  visit('/users')

  expect(page).to have_text('Users')
end

Surprisingly, this time it does not work. The sign in is done in a separate browser window and I end up with two open windows. One authenticated the other one not.
I broke that behavior down to a simple visit('/') that  should remember a string in the session. I created a fresh Ruby on Rails application with the following changes:
app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  after_action only: :index do
    session['memory'] = 'MEMORY'
  end

  def index
    render plain: session['memory'] || 'First try!'
  end
end

spec/system/systems_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Systems", type: :system do
  before do
    visit('/')
  end

  it 'visits /' do
    visit('/')

    # halt to see two browser windows open at once
    # debugger

    expect(page).to have_text('MEMORY')
  end
end

Even though I changed nothing else besides installing rspec-rails I still get the described behavior. In this case, two browser windows are opened both showing First try!. I'd expect the test to work. Am I wrong?
You can find the (not) working demo application here.

Got it. I don't know where to find that knowledge, I certainly don't see it in the capybara docs, but I solved it.
In spec_helper.rb or rails_helper.rb add:
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by(:selenium_chrome)
  end

  config.after(:each, type: :system) do
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
  end
end

This seems to bind an example to a single browser window.
